# cross compilation for amigaos: 'autom4te2.64' error

Tags: gcc, makefile, cygwin, toolchain, amiga

I am trying to installe an environment of cross compilation Windows64 for AmigaOS3.x , but I have a problem that I can't solve .
When I run 'make' in the /toolchains/m68k-unknown-amigaos this error returned:

```
...
make[2] : on entre dans le répertoire « /usr/local/home/toolchains/m68k-unknown-amigaos/builddir/gcc »
(cd /usr/local/home/toolchains/m68k-unknown-amigaos/builddir/srcdir/gcc/gcc && autoheader)
sh: autom4te2.64 : commande introuvable
autoheader-2.69: 'autom4te2.64' failed with exit status: 127
Makefile:1103 : la recette pour la cible « /usr/local/home/toolchains/m68k-unknown-amigaos/builddir/srcdir/gcc/gcc/cstamp-h.in » a échouée
make[2]: *** [/usr/local/home/toolchains/m68k-unknown-amigaos/builddir/srcdir/gcc/gcc/cstamp-h.in] Erreur 127
make[2] : on quitte le répertoire « /usr/local/home/toolchains/m68k-unknown-amigaos/builddir/gcc »
Makefile:23380 : la recette pour la cible « all-gcc » a échouée
make[1]: *** [all-gcc] Erreur 2
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /usr/local/home/toolchains/m68k-unknown-amigaos/builddir »
Makefile:109 : la recette pour la cible « /usr/local/home/toolchains/m68k-unknown-amigaos/builddir/build-steps/bootstrap-compiler.d » a échouée
make: *** [/usr/local/home/toolchains/m68k-unknown-amigaos/builddir/build-steps/bootstrap-compiler.d] Erreur 2
```

i use:

- git://git.netsurf-browser.org/toolchains.git
- cygwin 32

is it my cygwin missing some thing or is it something else? I'm really blocks
thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution is to add a symbolinks like that:

```
$ ls -al /usr/bin/autom4te*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Administrator None    34 15 févr. 11:49 /usr/bin/autom4te -> /usr/share/autotools/ac-wrapper.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Administrator None 32181  4 mars   2015 /usr/bin/autom4te-2.69

Administrator@wks09 /usr/local/home/toolchains/m68k-unknown-amigaos
$ ln -s /opt/gcc-tools/epoch2/bin/autom4te-2.64 /usr/bin/autom4te2.64

Administrator@wks09 /usr/local/home/toolchains/m68k-unknown-amigaos
$ ls -al /usr/bin/autom4te*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Administrator None    34 15 févr. 11:49 /usr/bin/autom4te -> /usr/share/autotools/ac-wrapper.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Administrator None    39 16 févr. 12:19 /usr/bin/autom4te2.64 -> /opt/gcc-tools/epoch2/bin/autom4te-2.64
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Administrator None 32181  4 mars   2015 /usr/bin/autom4te-2.69
```